# C#: how to check if a MySqlConnection is using SSL or not?

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I know how to check whether SSL is used to connect to MySQL, from **command line**. Just enter "**status**" and look at the line which starts with "**SSL**". But how do I check it in **C#** on a **MySqlConnection**?

Comment: Have you tried to query [5.1.5 Server System Variables :: ssl_cipher](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ssl_cipher) since your connection?.

Comment: I realized that checking ssl_cipher does not solve the problem, because when I connect using command line, then enter "status", the line starting with "SSL" indicates it is SSL connection, but the ssl_cipher system variable is null.

Comment: Try [25.11.14 Performance Schema Status Variable Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-status-variable-tables.html). `mysql> SELECT \`VARIABLE_VALUE\` FROM \`performance_schema\`.\`session_status\` WHERE \`VARIABLE_NAME\` = 'Ssl_cipher';`.