# Check if MySqlConnection is using SSL

Tags: c#, mysql, ssl

I think my question is similar to [C#: how to check if a MySqlConnection is using SSL or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499339/c-how-to-check-if-a-mysqlconnection-is-using-ssl-or-not), but unfortunately it doesn't have good answers because it is unclear maybe. So here's my take:

I have created a new connection:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=example.com;Port=3306;Database=Foo;User Id=root;Password=foo;SSL Mode=Required");
```

How do I verify it uses SSL, is there something like `connection.IsOverSSL`?

**Edit:**

I tried using `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'`, but this gives me `Ssl_cipher` even if `SSL Mode=Required`:

The code I use is:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"]);
connection.Open();
var command = new MySqlCommand("SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE \'Ssl_cipher\'", connection);
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
}
```

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-encrypted-connections.html, it should give me `Ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`

Comment: I think there's no specific property provided to check if `MySqlConnection` uses SSL. The nearest way is capturing network traffic with external tool as given in these similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703027/how-determine-if-using-ssl-in-a-mysql-connection & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389921/how-to-check-whether-a-mysql-connection-is-ssl-encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the connection string for the word "SSL".  This would allow you to know if your IDbConnection is using ssl in this case.  For a list of the connection strings that you could use with MySql, please visit [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).  Let me know if this solves your problem.

I would try looking at the connection string.  Here is a solution to demonstrate this.

```
var connStr = "Data Source=example.com;Port=3306;Database=Foo;User Id=root;Password=foo;SSL Mode=Required";
var sslElement = connStr.Split(';')
    .SingleOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("SSL", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

var sslModeEnabled = (sslElement != null 
    && string.Equals(sslElement.Split('=')[1].Trim(), "None", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false);


Console.WriteLine($"SSL Mode Enabled: {sslModeEnabled}");
```

Comment: My problem is I don't trust the connection string - what if "the word SSL" has no effect? How do you know it does anything? Maybe it's not honored.

Comment: What do you mean you don't trust the connection string?  The connection string for MySql must be in a certain format correct?  Here is the reference [Chapter 6 Connector/Net Connection-String Options Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html).  According to their own documentation, you have only three options for the name. SSL Mode, SslMode, and Ssl-Mode.  All three have the word "SSL" in them.  The other alternative is to split on the ';' character and find the SSL element and look for its value to validate.  Does this help?

Comment: My connection string already has `SSL Mode=Required`. My question wasn't about that. I am not sure that the flag itself has effect, so I want to independently verify that the connection is actually SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't printing the second column of the query, this now works:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"]);
connection.Open();
var command = new MySqlCommand("SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE \'Ssl_cipher\'", connection);
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{reader.GetString(0)}: {reader.GetString(1)}");
}
```

It prints `Ssl_cipher: AES256-SHA` for `SSL Mode=Required`, and `Ssl_cipher:` for `SSL Mode=None`. On the other hand, I get `Ssl_cipher: AES256-SHA` even if `SSL Mode` is missing altogether so maybe it's on by default.